# Ajax call autocomplete html to be insered in page with innerHTML. Forms doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm developing a site. I want to innest some html code, generated by php page with ajax innerHTML.
It works, the page generated by php is loaded, but modified from the page that i want wo be uploaded.
THe main problem is that i have a form, it has to contain a button, to submit a request.
If i open the php page it works, the button is between  and , but when this page is loaded into the other page with innerHTML the form doesn't contain the button, it's closed immediately like  and not button

This is the ajax function to innest code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selection").change(function () {
        $("#body").empty();
        var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getStatistic.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { player: selected },
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += data;
            },
        });
    });
});
```

the result is

and here the other button

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I presume you want to append the response data from your AJAX call to an element with id = 'body'.

If you look at [innerHTML definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) you can see that when you assign a value, it clears all the element's descendants:

> A DOMString containing the HTML serialization of the element's
>   descendants. Setting the value of innerHTML removes all of the
>   element's descendants and replaces them with nodes constructed by
>   parsing the HTML given in the string htmlString.

So, since you are already using Jquery, you probably want to use [Append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) which adds the HTML as the last child of the targeted element.

```
$('#body').append(data);
```